# Media query to override inline CSS

Tags: html, css, media-queries, inline

I am trying to override my inline CSS in an email using a media query. I was able to get the tables to resize but I am unable to get the font style to change. Below is my CSS code as well as where I am trying to place it within the table. Also, am I using the comments function correctly? I believe I have also seen /* comment */

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {

table [class="wrapper"] {
    width: 100% !important;
}

td [class="headerText"] {
 font-size:11px !important;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
 color:#000000 !important;
}
```

```html
<!--Content header-->
<table width="100%" border="0" class="content">
  <tr  align="center">
    <td class="headerText">
<span style="font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:19px; color:##C03333">Sophisticated Sparkle <em>for the</em> Holidays</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "*Also, am I using the comments function correctly? I believe I have also seen /\* comment \*/*" The **only** comments valid in CSS are delimited by `/*` and `*/`.

Comment: What you are using are HTML comments. /**/ are CSS comments. Neither of them are interchangeable.

Comment: If you've already set fonts w/inline CSS, you can't change it with external CSS - that's the point of the "Cascade". Inline is the last stop in the process, so it will always overwrite external rules that come first.

Answer (score 3):

Just do this

```
td.headerText span  {
 font-size: 14px!important; /* adjust as needed */
 font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
 color: green!important;
}
```

**or**

```
td[class="headerText"] span { 
 font-size: 14px!important;
 font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif !important;
 color:#000000 !important;
}
```

for the second block of code, there shouldn't be space between **td** and **[**

[See the second block of code working here](http://jsfiddle.net/jchzrvmo/1/)